# Is a foreach array the best choice to change sql column names on my web page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

Okay so I am currently building a website using php and mysql.
 Here is my issue: 
Some of my columns in my database are such things as `US, Darke, and year2010`. Many of these column names are placed in drop down boxes so users can collect data. However, instead, I would like the names to be `United States`, `Darke County (OH)`, and `2010` for example. I am currently just using a bunch of arrays like the one below to change the values.

`$arrayLocation = array('Darke' => 'Darke County (OH)');`

Then, I use a `foreach ($array as $let=>$word) array` to access the names I want to display on my web page.

Is this the best way to go about changing the values for some of my column names? I can't really think of another way to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Values that can vary for an entity should be stored in a row, not a column:

```
User Attribute Value
1    Country   US
1    County    Darke
1    Year      year2010
```

This will eliminate the need to rename columns. If you want to normalize the *values* contained in the columns, you can use a mapping table:

```
Old       New
US        United States
Darke     Darke County (OH)
year2010  2010
```